# The simplest way of proving that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = |\mathbb{R}| = c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the simplest way of proving (to a non-mathematician) that the power set of the set of natural numbers has the same cardinality as the set of the real numbers, i.e. how to construct a bijection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

Comment: It all depends on how mathematical this non-mathematician is.  For the less mathematical I honestly think the simplest way would involve using Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder and phrasing the two halves as "there are no more reals than sets of naturals" and _vice versa_.  I think CBS is a theorem that a non-mathematician could be convinced of without too much difficulty; not with anything that would approach mathematical rigour, mind you.  Avoiding CBS seems to involve nitty-gritty details that would make the average non-mathematician glassy-eyed, and the heart of the ideas might become lost.

Comment: I completely agree with Arthur, moreover to the non-mathematician the fact that there are two different sizes of infinity (countable and uncountable) would already make them glassy-eyed and you'd lose them completely.

Comment: The non-mathematmatician in question is VERY, VERY, VERY MUCH non-mathematical, so that expressions like "arctan (x)" (or even the "tan (x)" itself!) don't shed much of a light to his picture. So I would very much appreciate as little of symbols of any kind as possible - maybe NONE? - and as much convenient "images" as one is capable of providing without reffering to, say, the Bible. Thanks in advance, J.

Comment: Wrong, Asaf: That there are different sizes of infinity, proven by, say, the diagonal argument, is totaly acceptable, moreover, easy to understand for me. But I do have troubles understanding mathematical symbols and notations. So if there is an explanation that resembles the diagonal agument - which in my eyes is more of a picture than anything else - than that would be the kind of an answer I'm hoping for.

Comment: @Jan: I am a set theorist. It's not that my research focuses on finding "roots of polynomials" and whatnot. In particular I deal in my M.Sc. with behavior of cardinals in the absence of the axiom of choice. I always enjoy trying explaining those to people, especially other barflies at the local pub. It is *very* baffling to people that there are different sizes of infinity. It is equally baffling when you see it for the first time *with* the full definitions and proofs, people telling you otherwise are likely to lack the actual understanding - and further discussion is just further confusing.

Comment: Also if you want an under that *you* can understand, this is a **very** different situation than asking "*I have to explain this fact to a bunch of folks in a few days, how should I approach that?*". Mostly because *you* can add to the question what *you* already know and understand on the topic.

Comment: @Jan Some theorems admit a "proof by picture," where you a give a convincing proof-sketch without actually writing anything down, but most theorems do not have proofs that fall under this category.  Something like "There is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$" will almost certainly involve at least a few steps and some non-trivial terminology. That doesn't mean it's complicated (it's just the composition of a few "nice" bijections), it's just not as basic as most ideas encountered in high school.

Comment: Asaf: Of course, it is ME that is need of a proof. My profession is   (german classical) philosophy (mostly Kant and Hegel), but I'm studying Alain Badou now (a french philosopher that talks about ZFC set theory a lot), so I wish to claryfy some basic things. I understand the diagonal argument proving that there is a number that cannot be presented anywhere in the "No infinitely" stretching list of, say, real segments between 0 and 1, etc. but I had another problem:

Comment: since I was informed, that Cantor could "collect" the set of R only by interpreting it as a power set of N, and since I was also informed that that was his basic motif for the introduction of the "power set" axiom in the first place, I just wanted to know, how can one grasp the mentioned equality without any profound mathematical knowledge - and since the "diagonalization" seemed acceptably cogent to me, I was just wandering if there could be the same case with the equasion of cardinalitys between R and P(N).

Comment: @Jan: Very good then, you should *edit* the relevant information into the question. What you know and don't know. Sure it is a very general situation right now, and mathematicians strive to solve the most general situation, but first we start with the situation at hand - then we generalize the solution. So please, add the relevant information to the question to reflect that it is *you* who is trying to understand, and not that you need to explain to *someone else*, since you're not mathematically trained I'd consider adding  a short list of what you already know about set theory.

Comment: @Jan:  You're studying Badiou?!  This might be causing problems later since I know that he also uses the concept of [forcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_%28mathematics%29) in his work (at least in "_Being and Event_", which I guess the original French would be "_L'Être et l'Événement_").  (When I discovered that some philosopher was using set theory in his philosophical work I sought it out, but utterly failed to make sense of it.  This is likely due to my lack of any real philosophical background.)

Comment: @Jan: Diagonal arguments are good for showing that certain things _cannot_ exist (or in rare and subtle cases that things which do exist cannot have certain properties, like the Gödel sentence having a proof). However here you must show that a bijection _does_ exist, so a diagonal argument won't be of avail. Also for technical reasons (as ordered sets $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ have fundamentally different properties), such a bijection cannot be entirely "smooth". Which explains what an effortless proof is not possible.

Comment: @Artur Fischer: I'm not worrying about the "forcing" too much since Badiou explains the general idea in farly siple terms. But the bijection I'm asking for is not explained there so I was simply qurious: If the P(N) is the most obvious way to mathematically discribe the continuum in terms of exemplifying it by N numbers, how can this be done in terms understandable to a non-mathematician, i.e. to me.

Comment: If you just want to describe $\mathbb{R}$ in terms of $\mathbb{N}$ then it's a COMPLETELY different question.

Comment: @you: I realy think that such a "describing of R in terms of N" (although I would prefer describing it in terms of P(N)) would be of a great help to me. Could You do it here or should I formulate this as a seperate question? Thanks, J.

Comment: I can give you a brief description in a comment and see if it's what you're looking for.  It's kind of a "call and anser" story.  In $\mathbb{N}$, one problem is that most numbers don't have negatives.  we fix that with the  integers $\mathbb{Z}$, which could be thought of as the smallest set containing $\mathbb{N}$ and the negatives.  The next problem is that we don't have inverses: the rationals $\mathbb{Q]$ fix that problem, and can be thought of as the smallest algebraic structure containing $\mathbb{N}$, all it's negatives, and all of the inverses.  The final problem is that (continued)

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ still has gaps: numbers like $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$ are not in $\mathbb{Q}$, even though we can find rational numbers arbitrarily close to them.  In some sense $\mathbb{R}$ is the smallest set containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and all the numbers that can be "approximated in $\mathbb{Q}$".  The technical details in rigorously defining $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ are subtle, and probably difficult for high-school level.  This is what _I_ think when I hear "describe the continuum in terms of $\mathbb{N}$," maybe not what you meant.

Comment: @you: Okay, this inclusions of N into Z, Z into Q and of Q (by approximatization) into R, where R is the first uncountable set (of this roe) is quite clear, thanks. But is it possible to do something simmilar with P(N)? To precisize myself: is it possible to intuitively explain why the uncountability of P(N) is not "bigger" nor "smaller" than the uncountability of R? (see cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Or by putting the question in historical terms: why did Cantor choose the P(N) - and not, say, just some other set - to compare it to R in the first place? What is it about the P(N), that makes it so appealing to make one starting to prove the bijection in question by it? What is it, that makes one (intuitevily) say: "I want to show just how big the R is - so, heck, why don't I just take the P(N) and start from here?!" I hope that the question is now clear enough.

Comment: Well, by the diagonalization argument we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is "larger" than $\mathbb{N}$, and an argument similar to Russel's Paradox tells us that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ ALSO "larger" than $\mathbb{N}$.  So why not compare these two objects?

Comment: @you: Well, that is what I do know, and the means for showing it are simple enough (1. to get a hold on the diagonalisation argument is realy easy, and 2. the set of all the "outer" (not-contained) representations of P(N) in N cannot have an adquate representation in N); okay. But are there similar nonmathematical means to show that both of these uncountable infinities are of the "same size"?

Comment: The standard ways of showing that two sets $A$ and $B$ have the "same size" are 1)give a bijection between $A$ and $B$, and 2) Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, which says "$|A|\leq |B|$ and $|B|\leq|A|$ $\implies\ |A|=|B|$", or in other words it suffices to give one-to-one maps both ways or onto maps both ways.  If you would like a nonmathematical way of showing two uncountably infinite sets have the same size, I ask: what do "uncountable" and "same size" mean, nonmathematically?

Comment: Khmmm, I'd say you've got a point there... Well, I was wandering if one could go one in pretty much the same way as with the proofs provides for the notions, applied with 1. ("uncountability") the (non-)relation between R and N, shown by the diagonalization, and 2., ("same size") one-to-one correspondence between the natural and even (or odd, or squared, etc.) numbers... All in all I'd say that it was exactly this supposition that drowe me in posing the question in the first place. (see cont.)

Comment: (cont.) But since: 1., no argument of this (realy simple) kind was provided in this site (although there were some nice tries), 2.  Marc van Leeuwen (see above) stated that "ordered sets R and P(N) have fundamentally different properties", and 3. I belive You, mathematicians, - I guess finally, the answer to my question would be that it is simply PRINCIPALLY IMPOSSIBLE to demonstrate such an answer in a manner that could be as simple as showing the correspondence of N to one of its subsets (i.e. evens, odds, etc.)? (see cont.)

Comment: (cont.) But still further on: since, 1., N cannot be put into the one-to-one correspondence with EACH of it's subsets - i.e. at least not with those that are self-referential (the set of all the "outer" (not-contained) representations of P(N) in N cannot have an adquate representation in N) -, since 2., the diagonal arg. is basically of the same (self-referential) kind, and 3., since both of these arguments combined show ONLY that both P(N) and R are non-countable, but not that they are of the same size: (see cont.)

Comment: (cont.): Then, finaly, I guess the main argument for the impossibility of the intuitive answer to my question would be that there just ain't no way to intuitively grasp still larger incountable set as R (implied that diagonalization counts as intuitive enough to devide the cardinalities of N and R), thus showing the way to divide it from the uncountability of R (and of P(N)). Or is there?

Comment: First let me remark that there is a simple way to show that every infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ can be put in one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb N$. Each and every one of them. It can also be shown that $\mathbb N$ cannot be bijected with its *power set*. These two are not very difficult to see and understand. I have to admit that I have absolutely no idea what does that mean for a set to be "self referential" and what is "the set of all the 'outer' representations of P(N) in N".

Comment: I also have to say that if you plan on making set theory based arguments without studying some set theory first... well, that's just wrong in so many levels.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my favourite (most intuitive one I've seen): Define the bijection in three parts

First is easy: take your favourite bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$.  (Even to a non-mathematician it is intuitively clear that one exists by just "contracting" $\mathbb{R}$, and one example can be give explicitly by $\frac{1}{\pi}arctan(x) +\frac{1}{2}$).

Then by considering the binary expansion of real numbers we *almost* get a bijection between $(0,1)$ and the set $S$ of infinite binary strings, where the number $0.1001110110010\dots$ corresponds to the string $0.1001110110010\dots$ etc.  I say "almost" because the binary strings $100000\dots$ and $01111\dots$ correspond to the same real number $0.10000 \dots = 0.01111\dots$  To a non-mathematician you could say "we can fix these problems because there aren't many stings with repeated $1$'s, compared to the set of ALL binary strings" and move on.
(To a mathematician, this is because a string ending in all $1$'s is determined by its prefix, which has finite length, and mathematicians know that the set of finite binary strings is countable, and furthermore by the diagonalization argument $\mathbb{R}$ is UNcountable.  This allows you to modify the natural map $S\rightarrow (0,1)$ into one which *is* a bijection using the method described at the bottom of this link: https://nrich.maths.org/discus/messages/67613/67678.html?1133563921  But like I said, to a non-mathematician these issues aren't important.)

Finally, another easy one: a binary string $s\in S$ is by definition a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s, which can technically be defined as simply a function $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$.  Such a function determines a subset $A_s\subset\mathbb{N}$ by "$a\in A_s$ iff $s(a)=1$" and similarly a subset determines a function (we call $s$ the *characteristic function* of $A_s$ in $\mathbb{N}$).  An intuitive way to think of this phenomenon as that a binary string $s$ goes through the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ one-by-one and decides if it is in the set $A_s$ (with a $1$) or not (with a $0$).  This correspondance gives the bijection between $S$ and the powerset $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Combining it all together, we get $\left|\mathbb{R}\right|=\left|(0,1)\right|=\left|S\right|=\left|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\right|$

P.S.  This is the sort of discourse in which the vast majority of people first come to understand this theorem, because this is the context in which it is phrased: sets and functions and clever bijections.  If you would prefer a more elementary description then I will paraphrase what Euclid told a general under Alexander the Great: there is no royal road to mathematics.  This is as elementary as I can make it without writing an introduction on set theory :)

Comment: Binary expansion doesn't give a bijection, though, because of the repeating nines problem.  (Repeating ones in this case, I suppose.)

Comment: Nuts, you're right.  Do you know of a way to modify it into a bijection, or do we need to invoke Schroeder-Bernstein somewhere? (thus making it a proof for non-non-mathematicians)

Comment: Update:  I found a discussion of the issue here: https://nrich.maths.org/discus/messages/67613/67678.html?1133563921  When I get a chance, I'll add the necessary fix to my post

Comment: It's not hard to replace this with injections in both directions. Then you don't have to worry too much about the repeating 9s problem

Comment: My problem with that is the question asked for an explanation for _non_ mathematicians, who I assume don't know Schroeder-Bernstein, but also valid.  What is your injection from $S$ into $(0,1)$?

Comment: Shouldn't the first bijection by $\frac{1}{\pi} \arctan(x) +  \frac12$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is WAY to mathematical for me. Is ther a discoursive explanation possible that doesn't involve mathematical symbols that are not encountered in high school?

Comment: Aside from replacing those symbols with definitions using English words and more basic symbols, probably not.  Unfortunately only a tiny amount of mathematics is encountered in high school, and in order to describe more complicated notions it is necessary to introduce new symbols.  If you don't like the "arctan" thing, just image taking $\mathbb{R}$ and contracting it down to unit length

Comment: That's the spirit "you", and that is also just what I had in mind when asking for the "discoursive explanation" - using words and elementary symbols, maybe also some useful (real or imaginary) examples and thing like this! So: is there a way of explaining the topic to a person who's IQ is above 100 but is NOT a mathematician? I would realy appreciate it! Thanks, Jan.

Comment: @Jan: If anything, this should be a leverage to attend a basic course on set theory, or you know god forbid pick up a book and study on your own. Not everything mathematical can be explained in high school level, there is a reason it's called "high school level".

Comment: Asaf is more or less describing my point.  If I replaced every notion that isn't entirely elementary with a discourse on what the idea means and represents, then the post would MUCH longer, and not much more understandable (part of the elegance of this solution is that some basic but annoying details and definitions are encapsulated by things like "arctan" and "binary string" and "function").  At that point, it is maybe best to find a source that already exists, and bang your head against it until you understand.  If I find a good reference, I will let you know.

Comment: @you: I wrote an answer earlier today (read: before midnight) to a question which was completely senseless when I first read it. Apparently someone who lacks proper set theoretical education read an answer of mine and was completely baffled by something. The answer he read was one to a question which requested "a completely intuitive explanation for the axiom of choice, axiom of determinacy, and why they are incompatible". That thread led to furious arguments between me and the OP that the "intuitive" examples are flat out misleading when translated later on. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) If someone understands just those arguments he did **not** understand what the axiom of choice was. Let alone the axiom of determinacy which is flat out a technical axiom, and you cannot explain what it is without first explaining what it determines and why it is needed. As a result of all these questions I grow tired of the internet telling people of advanced results which they want to fully understand right away without sitting through books and courses and studying for years, months or even days. $${}$$ Sorry for the rant in the comments... :-)

Comment: Asaf: I understand what U mean and I didn't mean to show any disrespect by asking this without trying to "bang my had" over the matter myself. But the thing is that I know that it would take QUITE some time for me to get deeper into the matter, so I thought that someone could explain in simple-enough terms (if this is possible at all). My reasoning for this was simple: if I can manage to explain basic notions of, say, Hegel's philosophy to just anyone, not involving any profound philosophical terminology - maybe a mathematician could do the same. Thank's for understanding. Greetings, Jan

Comment: @Jan I think the bottom line is that these are the simplest terms in which you can describe a proof.  Also, you are speaking from the perspective of needing to explain it to someone else, but it seems you are having trouble understanding it yourself.  The first step in explaining it to someone else is understanding it.  It appears that to do this you need to develop your mathematical thinking, but luckily for you this is a classic theorem for helping you make that big leap from highschool math to real math.  Maybe it would help _me_ if you described where exactly you get lost?

Comment: @William The link is down.

Answer (score 4):

If it has to be a bijection I would go for continued fractions (as pointed out by J.D.):

1. State that for every real number there is only one shortest representation of it as a continued fraction ($a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a_i \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ and if the fraction is finite, $a_{\text{last}} \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$ ).
2. Then explain that $P(\mathbb{N})$ it the same as infinite sequence of 0s and 1s.
3. Show that infinite sequence of 0s and 1s is the same as sequence of natural numbers of any length (coded in base 1 with ones interleaved by zeros, i.e. 2,3,0,1,0,0,0... = 11 0 111 0 0 1 00000..., finite sequence have finite number of zeros, empty sequence = 11111...).
4. Sequence of natural numbers is a continued fraction:

   - empty sequence is 0;
   - sequence of length 1 should be transformed by any $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z} -\{0\}$ bijection;
   - if the sequence is of length 2 or greater, transform first term by any $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ bijection and add $1$ to the rest;
   - if the sequence is finite, increase the last term by additional 1.

This is the simplest **bijection** I could think of. But probably it doesn't have to be a bijection, in which case the argument is much simpler:

1. For a given set $X$, first sort it.
2. Take first smallest number, if it is odd, the result is negative.
3. Take the second smallest, this will be the integer part of the real.
4. Take the rest (in ascending order) all modulo $10$--this will be the tail of the real.

Going back:

1. Take only reals from $[0,1]$, where $1$ is represented by $0.(9)$,
2. $n \in Y$ if and only if the digit on the $n$-th place is odd.

**Edit 1:** to simplify a bit the step 4 in the bijection, you could interpret the sequence of natural numbers in a way that the first one tell how many 1s are there on the end of stream.

**Edit 2:** I missed the case of finite number of zeros in (3), thanks to Marc van Leeuwen for pointing that out. I think that the result after the fix is even nicer than before.

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: Your step $3$ doesn't work if the bit sequence contains only finitely many zeros; you could make it code for a _finite_ sequence of natural numbers (exactly as many as there are zeros) in that case (which actually is an advantage since continued fractions can be finite; however note that finite continued fractions are two for one rational value). Maybe this is what you say in point 4 ("ends with infinite stream of zeros") but it is not clear which sequence you mean, and if it's the bit sequence, then an infinite stream of _ones_ is special.

Comment: @dtldarek: Just what does it mean that "P(N) it the same as infinite sequence of 0s and 1s"? How can I picture this in the simplest possible way? Thanks, J.

Comment: @Jan: That $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is in bijection with infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s is immediate: term $i$ of the sequence is $1$ if $i$ is in your chosen subset of $\mathbb N$, and it is $0$ if not. I'm surprised you should ask, since it would seem that the diagonal argument showing that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable already uses this image (or one very close to it).

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: Thank U, Marc, now I get it. But will Your surprise be any lesser, when I explain that for the proof of the uncountability of P(N) it was perfectly enough for me to understand that, say, the set of all the "outer" (not-contained) representations of P(N) in N cannot have an adquate representation in N? Thanks again, Jan.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Indeed my step 3 didn't work, I fixed that up. I know that there are two representations of every rational as a continued fraction, thus I worked with shortest representations--those never end with $1$ (in fact somehow I forgot to add +1 to the last term one more time, but that's just my own carelessness). Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, use $\{1,2,\ldots\}=\mathbb{N}$.

A. For each positive real $x\in (0,1]$ there is a unique infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$  such that $x = \sum_A 2^{-p}$.

(To find numbers in $A$ one could start with some $p$ so that $2^{-p}$ is at least half the distance to $x$, but not $x$ itself. Then continue with that idea for each remaining distance.)

B. Every infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ corresponds to an element of $(0,1]$ in this way.

(Have them imagine adding up all those $2^{-p}$'s and appeal to their intuitive sense of convergence of an increasing bounded series.)

C. Now just use $f(x) = \tan(\pi x - \frac\pi2)$ which takes $(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ (and don't worry about the endpoint $1$). This shows that the infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are equinumerous with $\mathbb{R}$.

(One could explain it by stretching $(0,1)$ out until it "becomes" $\mathbb{R}$.)

D. As the collection of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, this completes the proof.

(Wave hands and say something like "finite sets are smaller than infinite sets" ;)

Comment: The "stretching" of (o,1) into R is realy a perfect example of just what I had in mind when I asked for an explanation for non-mathematicians. But I then one can also imagine that "Sigmas" and the "2s to the power of -p" isn't exactly the language I+m used to... Thank U, J.

Comment: The uniqueness in point A (which is in fact "decimal" expansion in base $2$) fails, because of the "repeating nines" phenomenon: the sets $\{1\}$ and its complement $\{2,3,4\ldots\}$ both determine the number $\frac12$ for instance. This phenomenon complicates every "expansion" based construction in a nasty way.

Comment: @Marc - That's why i required that $A$ be infinite. Then there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bijection inspired by the one given by [dtldarek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26306/dtldarek), but I've tried to reformulate as non-technical as possible. Instead of continued fractions, I make use of the related [Stern-Brocot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern-Brocot_tree) tree (or better, one with root $0$ and completed with a reflected image added to its left so as to cover the negative numbers as well as the positive numbers).

[image: Stern-Brocot tree for positive numbers]

But I won't need a technical description of it. In fact I can do with *any* tree labelled by rational numbers (or one could even allow arbitrary real numbers), with the following properties:

- For any node labelled by a number $y$, the labels $x$ of all nodes in the left subtree below it have $x<y$, and the labels $z$ of all nodes in the right subtree below it have $z>y$.
- If at this node $y$ node one goes to the left child, and then keeps going from a node to its right child indefinitely, one gets a sequence of (increasing) labels $x$ that converges to $y$.
- If at this node $y$ node one goes to the right child, and then keep going from a node to its left child indefinitely, one gets a sequence of (decreasing) labels $z$ that converges to $y$.
- If from the root node one descends to the left (resp. right) child indefinitely, the decreasing (resp. increasing) sequence of labels obtained diverges to $-\infty$ (resp. to $+\infty$).

These properties guarantee that the (countable) set of all labels forms a dense subset of the real numbers (the set of all rationals in the case of the symmetrized Stern-Brocot tree), and that for any real number $r$ that do not occur in the tree, one has a unique a infinite path whose labels converge to $r$, which can be found by using the tree as a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree): when at a label $y$, descend to the left subtree if $r<y$ and to the right subtree if $r>y$. Note that since $r$ is not itself a label this is well defined, and *the infinite path so obtained will not beyond some point continue to go in one same direction indefinitely*, in other words, it keeps on (ultimately) changing direction, forever.

Now the basic idea is to use, given a subset $S$ of $\mathbb N$, the presence/absence of succesive numbers to determine the direction of descent in the tree; say go left at step $i$ if $i\notin S$ and right if $i\in S$. Except for the two extreme possibilities, the labels along the infinite path obtained converge, and taking their limit *almost* defines a bijection to the real numbers (with $\{-\infty,\infty\}$ added to it for the diverging extremes).

However the map is not injective: all numbers that occur as a label $y$ are the limit for $2$ different paths, both passing though the node labelled $y$: one that descends to the left child of $y$ and then to the right forever, and another that descends to the right child of $y$ and then left forever. This defect, as well as the diverging extremes, can *almost* be repaired by the following rule: for those paths that beyond some point continue indefinitely in the same direction (these correspond to subsets of $\mathbb N$ that are either finite or the complement of a finite set), stop after the last move in the opposite direction, and take as image the label of the node reached. This change removes the two infinite paths whose labels converged to $y$, and replaces it by the unique path that was of the form: descend to $y$, change direction there and after that never change direction any more.

The one tiny defect that remains is that for the two extreme paths, our rule stipulates to truncate after the last step in the opposite direction, which step does not exist: the natural thing to do here is to remove all steps, and map to the label of the root of the tree ($0$ for the symmetrized Stern-Brocot tree). The two subsets that "collide" here are the empty set and all of $\mathbb N$. To repair this I start by modifying $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ so as to "tuck away" (make disappear) the empty set. The following rule does this: for all finite initial segments, i.e. subset of the form $\{i\in\mathbb N\mid i<n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ (which includes the empty set for $n=0$), add to it the minimal element $n$ originally absent form it. This maps $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ bijectively to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, and after this transformation one can use the map described above, which now is a bijection to $\mathbb R$. Oof!

Comment: Interesting argument.  I wouldn't exactly call it non-technical though :P  It seems to require that you understand what it means for $\mathbb{Q}$ to be dense in $\mathbb{R}$, which most lay-people don't

Comment: @you: If a layperson doesn't understand that real numbers can be approximated arbitrarily well by rationals, but that it takes (in general) infinitely many of then to pick out a specific real number, then there is no point in explaining why the reals are uncountable.

Comment: @ Marc van Leeuwen: Oooof, indeed! I would say that this description realy is helpfull, although it took me just over 3 hours at least to get some feel for it. Thank you, Jan

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to make the steps as mathematically non-threatening as possible, even at the expense of elegance:

We start from any real number, and wish to transform it into an unique set of natural numbers, such that every subset of $\mathbb N$ is hit exactly once.

**Step 1:** Squeeze the real line into the half-open interval between $0$ and $1$:

- If the number was $0$, then it stays unchanged.
- If the number was a positive integer $n$, then replace it with $\frac 1{2n}$.
- If the number was a positive non-integer, say $+x$, then replace it with $\frac1{2(x+1)}$.
- If the number was negative, say $-y$, then replace it with $\frac12 + \frac1{2(y+1)}$.

(This is not a particularly nice way to do this, mathematically speaking, but it is easier to understand than many slicker alternatives).

Pause. Satisfy yourself that every number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) is hit exactly once.

**Step 2:** Write down the decimal fraction for the number. It will start by "`0.`" followed by a countably infinite sequence of decimals. If you can represent the number exactly with finitely many digits, top it up with infinite repeating `0`s that the back end. Don't use representations that end in infinitely many '9's.

(There's a considerable amount of mathematical sophistication being swept under the rug in this step, but I'm assuming you're intuitively familiar with decimal fractions, and know that $0.999... = 1$).

**Step 3:** Remove the initial `0.`.

Pause. Satisfy yourself that every infinite sequence of digits is hit exactly once, *except* that sequences that end in infinite repeated `9`s are *not* hit.

**Step 4:** Encode the digits as ones and zeroes, using a table such as

```
0 becomes 0000    5 becomes 0101
1 becomes 0001    6 becomes 0110
2 becomes 0010    7 becomes 0111
3 becomes 0011    8 becomes 10
4 becomes 0100    9 becomes 11
```

The precise details of the encoding are not important, except to note that if we encode any sequence of digits in this way, we don't need to keep around any separators between successive digits. You can reconstruct the digits without them, because the first bit of an encoded digit determines whether it's a 4-bit or a 2-bit encoding. Furthermore, a sequence that ends in infinite repeating `9`s (but only such sequences) would map to a sequence ending in infinite repeating `1`s.

Pause. Satisfy yourself that every infinite sequence of digits is hit exactly once, *except* that sequences that end in infinite repeated `1`s are *not* hit.

**Step 5:** Get the sequences that end in infinite repeated `1`s included, by this rule:

- If the sequence already has infinitely many `1`s (which must be interspersed with infinitely many `0`s in some pattern or non-pattern), then leave it as it is.
- If the sequence only has finitely many `1`s, *and it starts with a `0`*, then chop off the initial `0` and leave it otherwise as it is.
- If the sequence only has finitely many `1`s and starts with an `1`, then chop off the initial `1`, and *flip every remaining element in the sequence from `1` to `0` or vice versa*.

Pause. Satisfy yourself that every infinite sequence of zeroes or ones is hit exactly once, no exceptions.

**Step 6:** Take the subset of $\mathbb N$ consisting of the positions in the sequence where an `1` is found.

Satisfy yourself that every subset of $\mathbb N$ is hit exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

I will prove every reasonable "equinumerosity" involved. There is a key lemma ([Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)) that states that $|A|=|B|$ iff there is an injective map from $A$ to $B$ and an injective map from $B$ to $A$.

1. $|\mathbb{R}|=|(0,1)|$ is trivial: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(x)\right)$ is an increasing function that maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$;
2. $|(0,1)|=|[0,1]|$ is less trivial: take an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ such that $q_0=0,q_1=1$, then map $q_n$ into $q_{n+2}$ ([Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel));
3. $|(0,1)|=|2^{\mathbb{N}}|$ is tricky: every number in $(0,1)$ has a unique canonical binary representation, where *canonical* means that no tails of $11111\ldots$ are allowed: that gives an injective map from $(0,1)$ to $2^\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, if $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a sequence such that $a_i\in\{0,1\}$, the map
   $$ \{a_n\}_{n\geq 0} \mapsto \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2a_n+1}{5^{n+1}} $$
   sends $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ into a Cantor subset of $(0,1)$ in a injective way.
4. $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|=|2^{\mathbb{N}}|\,$ is trivial again: every  non-empty subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ can be associated with the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ in which $a_n=1$ if $n\in A$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise.

By $(4)+(3)+(2)+(1)$, $$\left|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\right|=\left|\mathbb{R}\right|$$
as wanted. The trickiest part comes from noticing that this approach shows that a bijection exists without an explicit construction: the "*i.e.*" in OP's question is not really an "*i.e.*", unless we are [constructivists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)).