# Bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been thinking for a while whether its possible to have bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I cant think of a solution. So my question is: is there a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with proof)?

Comment: Since you tagged this real-analysis, do you want the bijection to be continuous? If yes, then no such bijection exists. If no, then one exists.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft it doesnt have to be continuous.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247696/does-mathbb-r2-contain-more-numbers-than-mathbb-r1/ and the relevant links appearing there.

Comment: [Also related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123326/a-simple-bijection-between-mathbbr-and-mathbbr4-or-mathbbrn)

Comment: Amongst the zillion duplicates, I chose this one. I encourage others to add other duplicates when voting to close.

Comment: One way is to come up with a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $P(\mathbb N)$, the set of all subsets of the natural numbers. It is easy to find a bijection between $P(\mathbb N)$ and $P(\mathbb N)\times P(\mathbb(N))$ by splitting a subset of $\mathbb N$ into the even and odd elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. I think it is one of the results of Cantor. Take two real numbers and combine them by interposing their digit in the decimal expansion.

example:
$$
(0.1415\dots,0.7172\dots) \mapsto (0.17411752\dots)
$$

Comment: This doesn't quite work. See the first answer to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr).

Comment: well, this is only the idea... you can easily make it rigorous using the Cantor-Bernstein theorem.