# Example of functions that are onto but not one-to-one

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, examples-counterexamples

I have been preparing for my exam tomorrow and I just can't think of a function that is onto but not one-to-one.

I know an absolute function isn't one-to-one or onto. And an example of a one-to-one function that isn't onto is $f(n)=2n$ where $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Help?

Comment: Any fonction is surjective onto its image. Just pick a non-injective one.

Answer (score 17):

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a\\ \;\\ b\end{matrix}\right\}\begin{matrix} \searrow\\\nearrow\end{matrix}\{c\}$$

Comment: +1 nice Zev. I don't know why we always search for the complicated examples while we can easily find them around us. Love simplicity.

Comment: "+1" for wicked TeX. (And for a perfect "illustration" of the concept.)

Answer (score 6):

I have to sort $52$ cards by suit and stack them in 4 boxes labeled according to suit:

$52$-cards $\to$ ($4$ boxes)

$$f: \text{Set of $52$ Cards} \to \{spades,\; clubs, \;diamonds,\; hearts\}$$

Answer (score 5):

For an example of a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which is onto but not one-to-one, consider $$f(x)=x\sin(x).$$

Answer (score 3):

For example, $\sin(x)$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[-1,1]$, $x^2$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_+$, or $x^3+5x^2+x+1$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

- $x^{2k}, k\in\mathbb Z$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^+$

Comment: Nice example! +1 Hope you had a great day at Uni!

Answer (score 2):

In order for a function to be onto, but not one-to-one, you can kind of imagine that there would be "more" things in the domain than the range.

A simple example would be $f(x,y)=x$, which takes $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It is clearly onto, but since we always ignore $y$, it's also not one-to-one:

$f(2,1)=f(2,2)=f(2,12525235423)=2$.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. Since $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality, there exists a bijection between them.

Comment: There is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$, it's just not continuous. And no one knows what it is…

Comment: @Aeolian Actually there are definable bijections between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (for example, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123326/a-simple-bijection-between-mathbbr-and-mathbbr4-or-mathbbrn)

Comment: @TrevorWilson Thanks for the correction. I learned something new, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use this simple example $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,+\infty)$, $f(x) = |x|$

Answer (score 2):

$f(1)=1$, $f(n)=n-1$ for each integer $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any bijection of $\Bbb N$ with $\Bbb{N\times N}$, e.g. $f(n,m)=2^n(2m+1)-1$ and take $g(n)$ to be the projection on the right coordinate of $f^{-1}(n)$.

Easily this is surjective, but every point has an infinite preimage.