# Is it possible for these to be onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible for a linear map to be onto if:

1. The domain is $R^5$ and the range is $R^4$?
2. The domain is $R^5$ and the range is $M(4,4)$?
3. The domain is $R^5$ and the range is $F(R)$?

I know to be onto $\operatorname{rank} T = \dim W$ for $T\colon V \to W$.

My thoughts:

1. No, because $5 + \operatorname{nullity}T = 4$, thus $\operatorname{nullity}T = -1$ which isn't possible?
2. No, because 5 and $\dim M = 8$ are not equal?
3. Not sure about this one.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your question asks 'one-to-one' and your text asks 'onto'. These are two separate things. Which do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry, edited, I meant onto.

Comment: Well for a map to be onto, the dimension of the codomain (range) cannot exceed the dimension of the domain. Does that help?

Comment: Ahh, so 1. is Yes? Is the dimension of range of M(4,4) = 8? And as for 3. I'm not sure what the dimension of F(R) is.

Comment: What is $F(R)$?

Comment: @FrankMcGovern , what about http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123326/a-simple-bijection-between-mathbbr-and-mathbbr4-or-mathbbrn ?

Comment: Also, in latex, the $\to$ symbol is `\to`. And to get operators such as $\operatorname{nullity}$ and $\operatorname{rank}$, type `\operatorname{nullity}` and `\operatorname{rank}`, though $\dim$ is built-in as `\dim`.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos That post is looking at _arbitrary_ maps, while this one is restricting to _linear_ maps.

Comment: @tacos Those functions aren't linear, so they don't apply.

Comment: If $M(4,4)$ is the vector space of $4\times4$ matrices, its dimension is not $8$. If $M(4,4)$ is not the vector space of $4\times4$ matrices, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to concentrate in one single lemma: let $\,V\,,\,W\,$ be two linear spaces over the same field, then

**Claim:** There exists an *onto* linear map $\,V\to W\,$ iff $\,\dim V\ge\dim W\,$

The above is true even if the dimensions are infinite (at least with the aid of AC).

Comment: Make that $\gt$ into $\ge$, and I'll buy it.

Comment: Ok, done. It's $0.05 Klingonian dollars, please...and thanks, of course.

Comment: Sorry, all I have is upvotes.

Comment: I understand that seeing as how Frank posted something similar above: "Well for a map to be onto, the dimension of the codomain (range) cannot exceed the dimension of the domain." I've figured out the first two, but I can't figure out the dimension of F(R). If you could help me out on that I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I apologize if I sounded rude, that was not my intent. As far as what F(R) is, this problem I posted comes straight from my book, I suppose it assumes you should already know what F(R) is like you know what R4 and P5 are..

Comment: Surely, somewhere the book explains what $F(R)$ is.