# Easy accessible proof that $ |\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N}) | = |\mathbb{R}|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is there a **simple, easy to understand,** proof of the following?

$$ |\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N}) |  = |\mathbb{R}|$$

That is, the cardinality of the power set of the natural numbers is the same as the cardinality of the real numbers.

---

The suggestions question has so much discussion, I am not sure I can take the answer as settled. [The simplest way of proving that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = |\mathbb{R}| = c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118655/the-simplest-way-of-proving-that-mathcalp-mathbbn-mathbbr-c)

Comment: There's a (relatively) easy way to define an explicit bijection betaeeen the irrational reals and the infinite subsets of $\mathbb N,$ by considering the continued fraction expansion of the irrational. Since the set of f8nite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is countable, and the set of rationals is countable, you can thus show an explicit bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $P(\mathbb N).$ The key is proving that the continued fraction for an irrational number is unique.

Comment: First show that $[0,1]$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$. Then represent elements of $[0,1]$ as binary sequences which are equivalent to subsets of natural numbers.

Comment: @JohnDouma but the binary representation is not always unique.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sure, but it's just two representatives at most for each number. Just mod out by the equivalent binary representations.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Continued fractions establish a bijection between *sequences* of positive numbers and irrationals in the interval $(0,1)$.  The sequence can even have finite range.

Comment: @Penelope: It's easier to show that the Cantor set and $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ are equinumerous - because there's a bijection defined by one formula.  For $\Bbb{R}$ you need to stitch together several maps or use Schröder-Bernstein.

Comment: To keep things simple, you can see $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ as the decimal representation of the real numbers. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum#Alternative_explanation_for_%F0%9D%94%A0_=_2%D7%900